# Podio: "Item has been deleted" on PUT, but can retrieve item via GET

Tags: api, podio

For some items I have the following problem:

I can retrieve them via `GET https://api.podio.com/item/$itemId` (meaning the item is *not* deleted). But when I want to update the item via `PUT https://api.podio.com/item/$itemId`, it results in a HTTP 410 with the following body:

```
{
    "error_parameters": {},
    "error_detail": null,
    "error_propagate": false,
    "request": {
        "url": "http://api.podio.com/item/$itemId",
        "query_string": "",
        "method": "PUT"
    },
    "error_description": "Item has been deleted",
    "error": "gone"
}
```

Is there any wrong assumption on my side, or why do I get this error?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting and updating same item? Can you see this item via web? There is also a microscopic chance of caching issue but then it would be much more visible and I hope it not the issue

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio: Yes, I am sure, that I use the same `$itemId`. This item was actually manually deleted via the UI, so I suppose it was not visible there. Would you mind checking if this could be due to some (malfunctioning) cache or something else?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio: This can still be reproduced with the following URL: https://api.podio.com/item/720744601 (correct auth assumed..)

Comment: Are you still getting that item in calls like filter items (https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747) ?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio: No - at leas not with the following filter: 
```
{
 "filters": {
  "item_id": 720744601
 }
}
```

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio any news?

Comment: are you still experiencing same behavior?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio yes, I can still retrieve this item. Not sure if I made this clear, but I could not reproduce this with other workspaces. One thing that I noticed is that the item has set "type": "delete" on its "current_revision".